# How do i find difference of two columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to find if the difference between 2 columns. How do I achieve that?

For example,

```
select(col1-col2) output is 1
select(col2-col1) output is -1
```

Is there a way to get just the difference as 1 without the negative `(-)` sign?

Comment: Please take a few moments and make this a complete question by including sample data along with the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `abs()` function

```
select abs(col2-col1) as diff
```